# How to reduce or replace the else if statements in C language?

Tags: c, design-patterns, embedded, embedded-linux

I'm using the code as shown below

```
  if (strcmp(oid, ".1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.1.0") == 0) 
  {
      return 1;
  } 
  else if (strcmp(oid, ".1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.2.0") == 0) 
  {
      return 2;
  }
  ...
  else if (strcmp(oid, ".1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.n.0") == 0) 
  {
      return n;
  }
```

Now the problem is updated `n` value is `250`. Can anyone please give me any idea to reduce this `else` `if` statement?

I tried to search on StackOverflow but those answers are related to the other languages and I want an idea that I can implement in the C language.

Comment: Put the string constants in an array.  Then iterate over the array.

Comment: Parse the string, patch the pattern and extract the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strncmp()` to match the prefix (".1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1."),  extract the text value say by using `strchr()` and convert it with `strtol()` for the return, and match the suffix (".0"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int oid_sub(const char *s) {
    const char prefix[] = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.";
    if(strncmp(s, prefix, sizeof(prefix) - 1))
        return -1;
    char *end;
    // check n for under and overflow?
    int n = strtol(s + sizeof(prefix) - 1, &end, 10);
    const char suffix[] = ".0";
    if(end == s + sizeof(prefix) - 1 || strcmp(end, suffix))
        return -1;
    return n;
}

int main() {
    char *s = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.42.0";
    printf("%d\n", oid_sub(s));
}
```

I would prefer a regex based solution:

```
#include <regex.h>

int oid_sub2(const char *s) {
    regex_t r;
    const char regex[] = "^\\.1\\.3\\.6\\.1\\.4\\.1\\.53864\\.1\\.([^.]+)\\.0$";
    if(regcomp(&r, regex, REG_EXTENDED))
        return -1;
    regmatch_t m[2];
    if(regexec(&r, s, 2, m, 0))
        return -1;
    return atoi(s + m[1].rm_so);
}
```

Note, `atoi()` fails with 0 on error, so you could tweak the regex to ensure it matches numbers or use `strtol()` as above (but no need to check the suffix as the regex already takes care of that).

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Allan Wind. okay let me try once.

Comment: I was thinking about a similar idea. As someone has downvoted for unknown reason,
I have compensated for it.

Comment: I suppose your answer is worth preserving for the future reference anyway.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick. Do note that it's not completely equivalent. It skips checking for the ending ".0", but that's trivial to add if you want it. I also omitted the error check for `sscanf`, but that's also easy to add.

```
char prefix[] = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.";
if(memcmp(prefix, oid, sizeof prefix-1) == 0) {
    int n;
    sscanf(&oid[sizeof prefix-1], "%d", &n);
    return n;
}
```

If you are very certain the strings are in the correct format, you can skip the `memcmp` completely. Another approach, depending on your requirements is this:

```
sscanf(".%*d.%*d.%*d.%*d.%*d.%*d.%*d.%*d.%d.%*d", %n);
```

Do note that I'm using %*d for all but one integer. That means I'm reading them but not storing them.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want the value in the 2nd last field of the string.

Here's a rough cut. You should add checking before considering it done...

```
char *tmp = strdup( old );
char *lastSep = strrchr( tmp, "." ); // want to go back one more.
*lastSep = '\0';
*lastSep = strrchr( tmp, "." ); // now left of desired field.
int n = atoi( lastSep + 1 );
free( tmp );
return n;
```

Or, if you want to "walk the string" left to right...

```
char *sep = old;
for( int i = 0; i < 9 && ( sep = strchr( sep, "." ) ) != NULL; i++ )
    sep += 1;
return sep ? atoi( sep + 1 ) : -1;
```

Or, simply count the separaters, stopping when you please.

```
for( int cnt = 0; *old && cnt < 9; )
    if( *old++ == '.' && ++cnt == 9 )
        return atoi( old );
return -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple method using `sscanf()` to match the pattern and extract the number:

```
int get_id(const char *oid) {
    int n;
    char ch;
    if (sscanf(oid, ".1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.%d.0%c", &n, &ch) == 1 && n >= 0 && n <= 255)
        return n;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

This function will return `n` if the pattern has the expected form and the value is within [0 .. 255], otherwise it returns `-1`. Note however that it will accept potentially invalid strings such as:

- leading spaces: `.1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1. 123.0`
- leading zeroes: `.1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.0123.0`
- plus sign: `.1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.+123.0`